# Many-to-many relationship versus permission

Tags: permissions, multi-tenant, user-permissions

A user has a company_id and a many to many relationship with tasks.
Each user has a role.
Each role has permissions.

An admin should be able to see all tasks within the company.
A user should only be able to see his own tasks within the company.

What are the pitfalls of each approach?

1. Assign all admins to the m2m when a task is created
2. Include a see_all_tasks permission as part of the admin role

Answer (score 0):

Given that you already have roles and permissions configured in your application. You should be assigning the users the roles against a company, like Admins will have a `Administrator` role in all Companies.

Any user in the application will be having a role per company that allows him to perform his task in the context of the company.

Ex: I can be a `Admin` for CompanyA & `Enduser` for CompanyB. This should give you the desired result.

In case of having a consolidated list of tasks being shown across all companies, I will aggregate roles for each task based on the companyId and then enforce permissions.